# A reason to require having a tube run down from the mouth to the lungs in order to breath

Tags: biology, humans

I have a human character who wears a gas mask over their mouth connecting to a tube that runs down to the lungs. They're meant to have a birth defect that made it very difficult to breath hence the tube.

I originally thought about them having some kind of mutation that causes their windpipe to be flooded with some kind of fluid to achieve this but don't know how to go about explaining the biology of that. I've looked at esophageal atresia but that can be solved through surgery and woke tracheomalacia is a possibility as the tube would be there to prevent the windpipe from collapsing, I'm wondering if there are any alternatives?

Comment: Related:  a *tracheostomy* medical treatment. Check out the causes that require that. Found a link for you https://www.healthline.com/health/tracheostomy#uses

Comment: keep in mind such a defect would be fatal with todays medicine, in the future we may discover mant birth defects of the breathing system, so you can make something up

Answer (score 8):

## Asthma:

Your character has a particularly severe or variant type of [asthma](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health-topics/asthma). On top of whatever birth defects they may have, they need the respirator and breathing tube to protect them from irritants and allergens that trigger asthma, as well as to prevent their trachea closing in the middle of an [asthma attack](https://www.webmd.com/asthma/asthma-attack). They would likely have been suffering with this for years, possibly having built-in medication delivery in the mask and tubing to treat asthma attacks.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Collapsing trachea.**

This is a congenital disease of inbred little dogs.  The cartilage rings which hold open the trachea are floppy and the trachea can collapse from the negative pressure produced by breathing.

https://metro-vet.com/references/collapsing-trachea/

> If a patient fails to respond adequately to medical management or
> presents for the first time in severe respiratory distress, surgery or
> other intervention to open up the airway is the recommended treatment.
> Surgical management is based on stenting (which can often be placed
> with minimally invasive techniques utilizing fluoroscopy) or placing
> devices around or within the trachea to mechanically hold it open.
> Some facilities will place stents through the mouth and down the
> trachea, using real-time radiography/x-rays (fluoroscopy), avoiding
> invasive surgical procedures. It is important for owners to realize
> that stenting is not without its own set of short-term and long-term
> complications and so is often reserved for severely affected patients.
> The purpose of a stent or surgical intervention is not to stop the
> coughing, but to keep the airway open. Often stents will induce
> coughing just by their presence.

I like this for a fiction because 1: you wanted an inherited problem and this is   2: there are (to my knowledge) not people with this inherited problem, but I did not check.  I find it somehow more palatable to fiction a dog problem into a human.  3: your character might have other little dog aspects to him or her.

Your character might cough a lot.  Apparently these little dogs do.

Comment: I have known a person which suffered from such condition.

Answer (score 4):

Any of [many lung damage conditions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_therapy#Positive_pressure_delivery)

Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease (COPD), chronic bronchitis, and emphysema can all require tubes. If your lungs or throat are damaged enough by smoke that you can't effectively draw in air, you need a tube down to force air into the lungs.

> Patients who are unable to breathe on their own will require positive pressure to move oxygen into their lungs for gaseous exchange to take place. Systems for delivery vary in complexity and cost, starting with a basic pocket mask adjunct which can be used to manually deliver artificial respiration with supplemental oxygen delivered through a mask port.

> Many emergency medical service members, first aid personnel, and hospital staff may use a bag-valve-mask (BVM), which is a malleable bag attached to a face mask (or invasive airway such as an endotracheal tube or laryngeal mask airway), usually with a reservoir bag attached, which is manually manipulated by the healthcare professional to push oxygen (or air) into the lungs. This is the only procedure allowed for initial treatment of cyanide poisoning in the UK workplace.[76]

It's more common to run a tube down the nose, since then you can talk and eat and such.